# extracting text after br tag in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

[enter image description here][1]I have seen similar questions before but none of them has a correct working solution. That's why I am posting it.
So I need to extract the text after br tag. I am working on Selenium Python and have tried almost every solution from here but none of them worked.

This is the selenium python code:

```
 #extract received value
        received = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//span[@class="dash-label"])[1]').text
        print(received)
```

Attached is the image of the html code
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfCwS.png

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath code

```
received = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Received"]/..').text
print(received)
```